# Why does my vite react project add new canvas elements to the page body every time I save instead of replacing the existing canvas elements?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite

I'm trying to start learning ThreeJs (I'm also new to Javascript web development too). After looking at some tutorials, I started with vite and react, and then started with the basic rotating cube. That part works.

But from what I've read about vite, saving the file that I'm working in should be enough to reload it on the page. It doesn't. I inspected the page contents, and every time I save the file, 2x identical canvas elements are appended to the body of the page (rather than replacing the existing ones), meaning that I have to scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the new content (or reload the page, which defeats the purpose of Vite's fast refresh feature).

What did I do wrong? I set up a basic vite project, added a component in the App, and then followed tutorials to make a basic cube rendering, and somehow along the way I circumvented Vite's fast refresh. Help?

Github:
https://github.com/amdreallyfast/ThreeJsTutorials/tree/main/npmfrontend

Reproduce:

```
clone
cd <directory>/npmfrontend
npm install 
npm run dev
Open page in browser
Inspect page -> Elements
Open SceneRenderer.jsx
Make change and save (ex: rotation speed; repeat multiple times)
Notice how the body element on the loaded page keeps appending new canvases
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `renderScene` every time in your `render` function. In React, `render` function is called in every re-rendering / update.

Therefore, every update (hot reload in your case) will trigger the `render` function, thus creating a new DOM element.

It is generally an anti-pattern to manually create DOM elements when using React (unless you are exactly sure what you are doing). I would recommend using a Three.js React renderer like this instead: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber

If for some reason you really want to do it, you can consider calling it during `componentDidMount` lifecycle in your React App and be sure to clean it up during `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle. You can read more about them here: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#componentdidmount

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I've started to look into react-three-fiber